# VBA: convert to pdf script that ignores blank cells in the conversion

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code that converts sheet "ConversiePDF" into PDF.
The problem is that the whole sheet is generated by formulas and half of the sheet is beeing populated with data and the other half remains blank (**with formulas running but returning ""**)

My code converts the whole sheet that goes as far as row 1000 and generates 32 pages (of witch 30 are empty - just the table with no real data)

I need it to ignore the blank cells where formulas returned "" IF THE WHOLE ROW from A to Q is empty or returns "". (if only one-two or three cells from a row are empty this should NOT apply)

Please help..

```
'This is my code till now: 

Dim ThisRng As Range
Dim strfile As String
Dim myfile As Variant

'Selectie Sheet pentru conversie
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ConversiePDF")
Set ThisRng = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
End With
```

Thank you..

Comment: have you tried with filter (out empyt rows) which could be set manually or by VBA code? you not necessary need to check all columns, possibly check of one will be enough to decide if row is empty. You could also check either `SUM()` or `COUNT()` (or other COUNT formulas depending on type of data you have) results and decide if row is empty and hide it.

Comment: I checked with excel filter and it works. Only turn into pdf the remaining cells but i need it in vba to do that auto. Im checking the internet for the right code but couldn't find something that i can integrate (probably cuz i'm relatively an idiot with vba)

Comment: Ok. I managed to get the following code to convert to PDF only the cells that have values but it also delets my formulas that return "" from the sheet. I need those formulas to remain in the sheet (permanently) but not be shown in the pdf if "" ; <BR> Code: Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" 'column A
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>" 'column E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'BUTON CONVERSIE PDF - ANGAJATORI
'DESCRIPTION: CONVERSIE A UNUI SHEET IN PDF
Dim ThisRng As Range
Dim strfile As String
Dim myfile As Variant


'Selectie Sheet pentru conversie
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PDF ANG").Visible = True

'Selectie filtru pentru ce sa converteasca
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PDF ANG").Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" 'column A
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>" 'column E

'Selectie raza pentru conversie
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PDF ANG")
Set ThisRng = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
End With

'Prompt for save location
strfile = "Selection" & "_" _
& Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") _
& ".pdf"
strfile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strfile
myfile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(InitialFileName:=strfile, _
FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
Title:="Select Folder and File Name to Save as PDF")
If myfile <> "False" Then 'save as PDF
ThisRng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
myfile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Else
MsgBox "No File Selected. PDF will not be saved", vbOKOnly, "No File Selected"
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PDF ANG").ShowAllData
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PDF ANG").Visible = False

End Sub
```